# PyDev Code Analysis not working in Aptana Studio

Tags: python, eclipse, aptana, pydev, code-analysis

I have a couple of Python projects which I imported into Aptana using "`Import` --> `Existing Folder as New Project`"

The import is successful, I can run and debug scripts inside Aptana. However, for some reason I cannot get PyDev's code analysis working.

All settings in `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `PyDev` -> `Editor` -> `Code Analysis` seem to be correct:

- `Do code analysis?` is checked
- `pep8.py` is set to run and report results as Warnings

I run it by right-clicking on a file and choosing "Run Code Analysis":
[image]

The following window appears shortly, but then it closes and I see no results (i.e. 
nothing on the "Problems" view, no red underscore under parts of the code, etc.):
[image]

Any idea what might be wrong? Or where I should look for to get more details on what's going on under the hood (log files, etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you did not set up the source folders properly (those are the folders that represent your PYTHONPATH for this project). See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf.html for details on how to configure that.